# java.lang.NullPointerException: The 2th element is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

In Activity :

```
Double[] numbers = new Double[33];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length (); i++) {
    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject ( i );
    Double price = o.getDouble ( "totalprice" );
    numbers[i] = price;
}

Observable<Double> observable = Observable.fromArray(numbers);

                        MathObservable
                                .sumDouble(observable)
                                .subscribe(new Observer<Double>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                                        Log.d( TAG,d.toString() );
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(Double aDouble) {
                                        System.out.println("Sum: " + aDouble);
                                        Toast.makeText( getContext() ,aDouble+"" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                                        //if you want int convert here
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                        Log.d( TAG,e.getMessage() );
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        Log.d( TAG,"complete");
                                    }
                                });
```

I want total price by using RXJava.
But error occurs :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: The 2th element is null

There is value in array

number = {75.0,40.0}

Comment: The error indicates the element at index 2 is null.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a `Double` array of size 33. When you do this you get an array of size 33 with every element equals to `null`. So element at position 2 is `null`, just like every other element, except elements at position 0 and 1, which you are assigning.
RxJava2 doesn't support `null` values in streams, so it throws that exception.